# passing function date to offset cell with value

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, runtime-error

I have written the following code that assigns a date to a cell within col a that has a value greater than 0. Within this code I have include a function that passes the current date. This was included purely for a learning purpose. I have thought I could quite easily just write r.value.offset = now().

However when I run this code it throws the following error message 'method range of object' global failed. see code below

```
Sub gdate()

   Dim i As Long, r As Range, coltoSearch As String

    coltoSearch = "A"

    For i = 1 To Range(coltoSearch & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set r = Range(coltoSearch & i)
        If Len(r.Value) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "No Value, in " & r.Address
            ElseIf Len(r.Value) > 0 Then
            Range(r.Value).Offset = date1
        End If
    Next i

End Sub


Function getdate(ByRef date1 As Date)
Dim d As String
 d = Now()
 date1 = d
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did was "nearly perfect", just a minor tweak:

```
Sub gdate()
    Dim i As Long, r As Range, coltoSearch As String
    coltoSearch = "A"
    For i = 1 To Range(coltoSearch & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set r = Range(coltoSearch & i)
        If Len(r.Value) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "No Value, in " & r.Address
        Else
            r.Offset(0, 1) = Date
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

Here is a function that returns the current date/time in a specific format as a **String**

```
Function getdate() As String
    getdate = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")
End Function
```

an alternative is to have the function just return **Now** as a true Excel date/time and apply the formatting to the cell externally

**EDIT#2:**

This version protects a previously entered date/time:

```
Sub gdate()
    Dim i As Long, r As Range, coltoSearch As String
    coltoSearch = "A"
    For i = 1 To Range(coltoSearch & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set r = Range(coltoSearch & i)
        If Len(r.Value) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "No Value, in " & r.Address
        Else
            If r.Offset(0, 1) = "" Then
                r.Offset(0, 1) = Date
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: So So Close! :) Thanks for pointing it out, I am learning so i appreciate this. The function that I wrote how would I reference that?

Comment: Do you want the function to return a true **date** or the string representation of a date??

Comment: true date meaning system date? Ideally I would like to show the date and time this code above I wrote a function that returns the date and time.

Comment: Values in A would have a date time stamp in the offset cell found in col B A1 = 12, A2= 32, A3= 45 B1= 20/04/2014 13:51, B2= 20/04/2014 12:04 ......

Comment: Cool to see, fairly simple and straight forward. I have just thought this code will change date and time everytime the macro is run. I would have to include a condition where if there is a offset cell with a value already in there it should not change it.

Comment: psudo for this condition - 'if offset has value then don’t put date in that cell'